# How can I resolve my fatal error during Drupal installation within XAMPP?

Tags: installation

I'm installing Drupal in XAMPP in localhost (I am using Windows).

I went to localhost/drupal (which maps with the files on my C drive -> xampp -> htdocs -> drupal) and proceeded.

Right after I entered the details on the databse page and proceeded, it gave an error like so:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_access() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\core\modules\system\system.module on line 2134".

When I return to localhost/drupal I keep getting the same error.

How can I resolve this fatal error?

Comment: what version of drupal and what version of xampp?

Comment: @MohammedShameem Latest version of drupal, i just cloned it 1 hour ago. XAMPP version 1.8.2

Comment: 7 or 8? did you use git or did you download it?

Comment: i used smartgit (latest version) and added their repository by using the link : http://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git